# Get UTC/GMT timestamp in infosphere streams

Tags: bigdata, infosphere-spl

I have been using the `getTimestamp()` method of Infosphere Streams to get the current time stamp. However with multiple instances running in various timezones, its difficult to sync. Is there any way to retrieve the GMT timestamp of the given instant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just overlooked the API documentations... `gmtime(timeStamp,resultantTuple)` solves the problem.